# Unable to add permissions to the firebase realtime databse

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want to add the permissions so that only authenticated user can read/write data into my database.
But I tried to write different types of permissions and I get the same thing everytime.

> DatabaseError: Permission denied

If the read and write are set to `true` then only I can read/write into the database.

```
//this works
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}

//does not work
{
  "rules": {
    "userdetails":{
      "$user_id":{
    ".read": "$user_id === auth.uid",
    ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}

//this also not works
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.uid != null",
    ".write": "auth.uid != null"
  }
}
```

The code for entering the data is this:

```
String userfirebaseid=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("userdetails").child((userfirebaseid));

Map setValues = new HashMap();
setValues.put("eMail ID",user_id);
setValues.put("Name",user_name);
setValues.put("Phone Number",phn_no);
reff.setValue(setValues);
```

My Firebase Database

[image]

Please Tell me what I'am doing wrong in this.

Comment: If you log the value of `userfirebaseid` just before `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("userdetails").child((userfirebaseid))`, what does it print? Also note: you have double parenthesis around `userfirebaseid` in there, which you'll probably want to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly usage of below code is correct.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

The code for entering data looks fine, try replacing `Hashmap` to push your values and add a `onFailureListener` so you can see what `error` you're getting:

```
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
map.add("eMail ID",user_id);
map.add("Name",user_name);
map.add("Phone Number",phn_no);

reff.push().setValue(map).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

You can read more about saving data on your Realtime Firebase Database [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)